# Can I replace a section of copper pipe with flexible PVC?

Tags: plumbing, copper-tubing, pvc

The valve at the end of the supply line for my ice maker started leaking from that top.  In trying to remove the valve, I twisted the copper supply line.  The section of pipe is 6 inches, and the twist is right above a 90 degree elbow.  I have a replacement valve, but I'm wondering if it would be okay to cut the elbow off and run a piece of flexible PVC from the copper line to the new valve using a compression fitting to join them. Are there any issues with this I'm not seeing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the Sharkbite or Gatorbite connectors as a junction for copper and PVC. Sharkbite and Gatorbite connectors are "snap together" connectors available at Lowes or HomeDepot, you can put copper in one side and PVC in another.

Comment: In researching SharkBite, I found that my initial idea is not code compliant being inside a wall.  SharkBite is allowed in the wall, so I will use that with CPVC instead of flexible PVC.

Comment: Use PEX if it is code in your area. Also, be very careful with how you cut the copper -- SharkBite needs a clean cut.